# HTML and CSS Organize divs vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following problem:

I have body width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;

I want to put several divs one below the other one below the other and when you reach the limit move to the side

below follows the illustration

[image]

I'm sorry for my English is not my primary language

Comment: what's the purpose of `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Share your html code

Comment: Resolved, I use the -webkit-flex

Answer (score 0):

explanation in the comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvc5mq3r/

```
$(function(){

    // function to add content vertically
    function addVertically(div, content){

        // max blocks per column
        maxBlocksPerCol = 10;

        //determine which column to add to
        col = null;

        div.children("div").each(function(){

            if($(this).children("div").length < maxBlocksPerCol) 
                col = $(this);
        });
        if(col == null){
            col = $("<div class='column'></div>");
            div.append(col);
        }

        // finally, append the content to the appropriate div
        col.append(content);
    }


    // the div to add your columns to
    div = $("#columns");

    // some sample content for each added div
    content = "<div class='block'></div>";

    // test, adds 15 blocks vertically
    columnsToAdd = 15; while(columnsToAdd--) addVertically(div, content);
});
```